# RSS feed gets updated with a question which hasn't been changed for quite a while

Tags: support, feed

I'm subscribed to the tag feed in Google reader: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/wix. Sometimes the feed gets updated with a question, which is quite old and looking through the entire thread I don't see any recent changes, which might lead to the feed update. I mean, no new answers, no new comments, no new edits, etc.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user may have automatically bumped the question. It's purpose is to highlight slightly old questions so that they get more attention/responses/answers. It randomly picks eligible questions.

Comment: This makes perfect sense - I forgot that @Community is watching everyone ;-)